# python assignment and logical operator question

Tags: python, python-3.x

what does this python statement mean?

```
dp[i] = dp[i] or dp[i-num]
```

Assume that there is no for loop or if statement associated with it. please let me know of you want any more information.

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Welcome. [Read](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#an-informal-introduction-to-python) this tutorial before starting to code, it will be really helpful.

Comment: What about this statement *do* you understand?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Comment: You'll find this helpful I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658308/how-does-the-logical-and-operator-work-with-integers-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### edit: as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879272/how-to-understand-the-result-of-none-or-false-false-or-none-none-and-fals):

*'or' returns the first true or last false answer.*

It seems that either the first or the most true value is assigned to your variable. See these interactive experiments.

```py
>>> foo = 0 or True
>>> foo
True
>>> foo = "" or type
>>> foo
<class 'type'>
>>> bar = 2 or "two"
>>> bar
2
>>> bar = "two" or 2
>>> bar
'two'
>>> bar = [None, False, True, "something"]
>>> foo = bar[0] or bar[1]
>>> foo
False
>>> foo = bar[1] or bar[2]
>>> foo
True

# but look at this last one....
>>> foo = None or False
>>> foo
False
```

Nothing shows up.
What struck me is this last one...

```py
>>> foo = False or None
>>> foo
>>> print(foo)
None
```

Does this mean "None" is more True than False? But False is False enough to be printed by the console.. I think I'm missing somewhere here but I thought I'd share.

Answer (score 0):

If `dp` is any list and `i` is greater than `num` so that the index doesn't go out of the allowed range, this is equivalent to `dp[i] = dp[i] if dp[i] else (dp[i-num] if dp[i-num] else False`.

`dp[i]` and `dp[i-num]` will be set to true if the value at the given index is different from None or False.

Example:

```
> dp = ['a', True, 5, None]

> i, num = 3, 1

> dp[i] = dp[i] or dp[i-num]

> dp
['a', True, 5, 5]
```

In this case, it's the same thing to do:

```
dp[i] = None or 5
```

So the return will be `5`.
This changes the value of dp at index `i` (so 3) to the return value(5).