# what is None,True,False in python?

Tags: python, keyword

Are they keywords, constants, or functions? If they are constants, what are their types? It seems python has no type of boolean.

Comment: `None` is of type `NoneType`. `True` and `False` are of type `bool`. You can type `type(True)` or for any variable on the REPL to figure out its type

Comment: “It seems python has no type of boolean.” Eh? `bool`? Anyway, they’re keywords that act as constants/literals, because Python doesn’t have that kind of constant. (In Python 2, only `None` is a keyword, and you can actually assign values to `True` and `False`.)

Comment: I dont understand why this question received so many downvotes.

Comment: Not that I downvoted, but it very easily google-able stuff as it's been asked/answered in many different places

Comment: Possible duplicate of [False or None vs. None or False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914667/false-or-none-vs-none-or-false)

Comment: Open a shell and type `bool`. It comes back as `<type 'bool'>`. So python does have a boolean type.

Comment: This is now the top answer on google for "Is None True in Python", so I think it could use a link to a canonical answer

Comment: I didn't understand why this question  has gotten negative feedback, I think some are quick to judge and punish.

Answer (score 3):

The [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/) has it all, one just has to know where to look:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html

> A small number of constants live in the built-in namespace. They are:
>
> **False**
>
> The false value of the bool type. Assignments to False are illegal and raise a SyntaxError.
>
> **True**
>
> The true value of the bool type. Assignments to True are illegal and raise a SyntaxError.
>
> **None**
>
> The sole value of the type NoneType. None is frequently used to represent the absence of a value, as when default arguments are not
> passed to a function. Assignments to None are illegal and raise a
> SyntaxError.

Also

- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords
- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

> **None**
>
> This type has a single value. There is a single object with this value. This object is accessed through the built-in name None. It is
> used to signify the absence of a value in many situations, e.g., it is
> returned from functions that don’t explicitly return anything. Its
> truth value is false.

and

> Booleans (bool)
>
> These represent the truth values **False** and **True**. The two objects representing the values False and True are the only Boolean objects.
> The Boolean type is a subtype of the integer type, and Boolean values
> behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all contexts,
> the exception being that when converted to a string, the strings
> "False" or "True" are returned, respectively.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth

Further reading

- http://python-history.blogspot.de/2013/11/story-of-none-true-false.html
- [False or None vs. None or False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914667/false-or-none-vs-none-or-false)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html is a good place to look!

Comment: I'm still confused. They are listed as keywords in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords, but as constants in https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html. So, they are keywords and constants at the same time?